# trying to build mysql query with counts and group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, group-by

How can I build a query to do the following?

1. Grouping by phonenumber
2. Where That Grouping has over 5 different names

data fields:
id, phonenumber, name

I've tried:

```
SELECT count(phonenumber), phonenumber, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM list
group by phonenumber
having count(phonenumber) > 5
```

but it's timing out, so not sure if that's the right format.

fake data:

```
id | phonenumber | name
1  | 555-5555    | joe
2  | 444-4444    | joe
3  | 555-5555    | joe
4  | 555-5555    | dan
5  | 555-5555    | Ben
6  | 555-5555    | Griff
7  | 555-5555    | Sam
8  | 555-5555    | Jim
```

desired output:

```
count(phonenumber | phonenumber | GROUP
7                 | 555-5555    | joe, dan, Ben, Griff, Sam, Jim
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Provide your table definitions, sample data, and desired output and what you've got yourself so far, so that we can see your effort and won't guess what is it really you want us to help you with.

Comment: thanks -- will fill that in a bit, and I appreciate the information on what more i need to post.  Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired output...

Comment: Well, it looks like your query works just fine. Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc035/2).

Comment: Yes, phone number can be tied to multiple people, and to the same person.

Comment: thanks to @peterm it looks like your original query is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your query works just fine. Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc035/2).

If you need to get only `DISTINCT` names then you can do it like this

```sql
SELECT COUNT(phonenumber) AS `count`, 
       phonenumber, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name) AS `names`
  FROM `list` 
 GROUP BY phonenumber 
HAVING COUNT(phonenumber) > 5
```

And here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc035/8) for that.

Comment: Thanks!  slow db appears to be the problem giving me timeouts.  And thanks for the sqlfiddle link!  never seen that site.

Comment: @user2069972 Make sure you have Indexes defined for columns that are commonly queried. That will increase your database performance by quite a bit.

Comment: @user2069972 You're quite welcome. Happy coding. And thanks for being so compliant and quick with improving your question.

Comment: Thanks!  navicat was just being slow turns out.. went command line and  query only took 2 mins!